# 3/4 creature versus a 3/3 creature, why would the 3/4 creature die?

Tags: magic-the-gathering, mtg-arena

I found myself in a situation where my adversary attacked with a 3/3 creature and I blocked him with a 3/4, what happened later was that both creatures died.

Shouldn't my 3/4 creature be alive with 3/1? In other situations this was always the case and I didn't get confused.

To clarify, there was no instantaneous card activated and there was no active spell that could be used to improve the enemy's creature.

Comment: From my time playing MTG arena, and seeing the decks and cards it gives, was their creature a zombie and they had Death Baron on the field also? That would mean your creature died because of deathtouch.

Answer (score 4):

Damage does not modify toughness, so your creature will not become 3/1. It will remain a 3/4, but it will be marked with three damage. (Some video game versions of Magic show this as 3/1, but that is inaccurate.) That alone is not enough to kill it, so something is missing from your description.

- Maybe your creature was marked with damage earlier in the turn.
- Maybe an effect enhancing your creature's toughness was removed.
- Maybe the attacking creature had deathtouch.
- etc

A more detailed description of the scenario would allow us to give a more detailed answer.

Comment: By 3/1 I mean during the combat phase, after that yes, the creature will remain a 3/4.
I will try to pay more attention next time, thank you very much for the answer.

Comment: No, I stand by what I said. The creature is NEVER becomes 3/1 in the scenario you presented (because damage does NOT reduce toughness (wither/infect aside)). If Arena shows 3/1, it is lying to you. Furthermore, marked damage is removed at the end of the turn (Cleanup Step), not when the Combat Phase ends.

Comment: I want to add that unfortunately Arena does display damage as a toughness decrease, like Magic Duels did. So, the most likely explanation here is that the 3/3 did have deathtouch, which would result in the 3/4 immediately dying.

Comment: @murgatroid99, I did mention that, and another equally likely scenario: Say the creature was a Soldier, and their Aven Brigadier died from blocking a different attacker.

Comment: Right, that would make sense too.

Comment: My money is on deathtouch.  Was the attacking creature a [Nightveil Predator](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?multiverseid=452941) by any chance?